# looking for a C++ function in the current buffer

Tags: lunarvim

I have a large codebase with huge C++ files each containing hundreds of functions. Is there a way to jump to a specific function in the current buffer just by knowing the name?
I can't use **gd/gD** because there is nothing under the cursor, **gr** wont do either because it will search everywhere... what I am doing right now is **/func/** but it returns every matching text in the buffer (so any call/mention to func as well), then I can use gd on the first occurrence..

Is there any faster/cleaner way to do it? on Vim I used fuzzy ctrl-p, which is like ctrl-p but for functions. I cant find anything similar on lunarvim and I dont want to look for plugins if something is already available.

Answer (score 0):

Telescope is perfectly capable of searching through lsp symbols:

```
:Telescope lsp_document_symbols
```